# Group data by date range and display query results in tabular form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to aggregate payment histories under a single due date and create an html table similarly displayed below.

```
+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| Date Due     | Amount Paid   |   Date Paid    |
+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| Nov, 1 2012  |           $10 |   Oct, 21 2012 |
|              |           $15 |   Oct, 18 2012 |
| Oct, 14 2012 |           $20 |   Oct, 13 2012 |
|              |           $20 |   Sep,  3 2012 |
+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

The problem I am facing is this:

The date due, amount paid, and date paid data fields are all in the same table row. The date due does not necessarily correspond to when the actual payment was made (maybe a payment was made 3 weeks late). Or... maybe two payments were received within the time frame of a single payment date due.

How can I efficiently tackle a problem like this and display it in a table? I've tried a few ways already and the code is too system process intensive.

EDIT: The rows in the table of the database currently look something like this:

```
+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| Date Due     | Amount Paid   |   Date Paid    |
+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| Nov, 29 2012 |           $10 |   Oct, 21 2012 |
| Nov, 15 2012 |           $15 |   Oct, 18 2012 |
| Nov,  1 2012 |           $20 |   Oct, 13 2012 |
| Oct, 14 2012 |           $20 |   Sep,  3 2012 |
+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

But the customer has to pay $50 for every due date. In this case, the customer split up their payments and it did not apply to the current due date because of the way the data is formatted in the table.

Unfortunately, I can not change anything in the database.

Comment: So you have payment histories that you're trying to aggregate to a due date? What is your table meant to communicate? Also, you should be able to do it in a query and just run through the rows and display them; no fancy logic. That's what the SQL is for, really.

Comment: The table is meant to communicate payments made for each due date. Sometimes customers will break up their payment into two or more payments. The problem is that since the payment due date in the database is supposed to correspond to each payment made (and is also on the same table row), sometimes it will appear that customers have made their payment in full, but in actuality only made a partial payment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes I'm trying to aggregate payment histories under a single due date! Thanks for wording that better. :)

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is [ledger accounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_ledger), where you can think of it as summarizing obligations and transactions against those obligations through a summing of the (rolling) debt and payment totals. What you *have*, though, doesn't at least appear designed to be transactional; the "Date Due" in fact is related to the account holder and sum of payments only through the relationship of the account holder. So Date Due should be in another table and compared to the total of payments. Date Paid is really just payment metadata.

Comment: In short, the Date Due only shows an obligation, but not much else. So you can show total payments to date (and ignore Date Due), or show payments by Date Due (maybe as a "delinquency" or deficit table??). You could put a column in the query next to Date Due with `'$50'` in it and then use that as a separate column. The only issue would if you have serial payments with Date Due entries, meaning you'd could do an aggregate `GROUP ON` on the Date Due to show payment totals for the obligation. Which could be useful.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, thats the conundrum. I was thinking the exact same thing - separating the date due column entirely and then sorting payment dates under that date due. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this while maintaining an html table format - it exceeds my knowledge of php.

Comment: Focus on the query; the HTML table is just a particular view formatting of the results of the rows and columns returned in the query. Do you have phpMyAdmin to run some queries and see the results easily?

Comment: Yes. I've been testing out an array of queries as is. I'm also testing it directly in php.

Answer (score 1):

The query will be

```
 select * from table_name order by Date_Due ASC,Date_Paid ASC , Amount_Paid ASC
```

This query first do order by of `Date_Due` by ascending and after that by `Date_Paid` and `Amount_Paid`.

Comment: I think this would probably be the correct query anything after that should probably be done in the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: Acording to OP's table, it should be DESC - ASC - DESC.

Comment: That wouldn't work for this table - if they pay early, it would cut off some of the payments entirely as the payment date would exceed the due date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is on a single flat table, it sounds like you simply want each due date to display only once (instead of with every row).

If thats correct, I think you should just approach the problem in your php code that constructs your table rather than trying achieve this in your mysql result.